# Metadata and annotation definition

Tags: java, annotations, metadata

In the oracle annotation tutorial said that annotation provide metadata for application. What does mean *metadata* and what's difference between typical data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metadata is data about your data - lets say you had a DB table full of entries.  The rows or tuples are the data, and the columns would be the metadata; they define what each value *is* for any given row.

Annotations are code snippits you put in at the java class or method level that further define data about the given code, but without changing any of the actual coded logic.  If you annotate a method, the execution of that method does not change, but you have specified extra data about the method other java apps or the jvm might use in different situations.

@Override is a very common annotation, you would put that at the method level to indicate you are either replacing or extending a method that was already defined.

Check out the wiki [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation).